# Use reflection to get attribute of a property via method called from the setter

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, attributes

*Note: This is a follow-up to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627659/what-ways-can-i-ensure-that-a-string-property-is-of-a-particular-length/3628000#3628000) on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627659/what-ways-can-i-ensure-that-a-string-property-is-of-a-particular-length)*.

I'm decorating a property's setter with an Attribute called `TestMaxStringLength` that's used in method called from the setter for validation.

The property currently looks like this:

```
public string CompanyName
{
    get
    {
        return this._CompanyName;
    }
    [TestMaxStringLength(50)]
    set
    {
        this.ValidateProperty(value);
        this._CompanyName = value;
    }
}
```

But I would rather it look like this:

```
[TestMaxStringLength(50)]
public string CompanyName
{
    get
    {
        return this._CompanyName;
    }
    set
    {
        this.ValidateProperty(value);
        this._CompanyName = value;
    }
}
```

The code for `ValidateProperty` that is responsible for looking up the attributes of the setter is:

```
private void ValidateProperty(string value)
{
    var attributes = 
       new StackTrace()
           .GetFrame(1)
           .GetMethod()
           .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestMaxStringLength), true);
    //Use the attributes to check the length, throw an exception, etc.
}
```

How can I change the `ValidateProperty` code to look for attributes on the *property* instead of the *set method*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to get a PropertyInfo from a MethodInfo of one of its setters. Though, of course, you could use some string hacks, like using the name for the lookup, and such. I'm thinking something like:

```
var method = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
var propName = method.Name.Remove(0, 4); // remove get_ / set_
var property = method.DeclaringType.GetProperty(propName);
var attribs = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestMaxStringLength), true);
```

Needless to say, though, that's not exactly performant.

Also, be careful with the StackTrace class - it's a performance hog, too, when used too often.

Answer (score 2):

In the class that declares the method, you could search for the property that contains that setter.  It's not performant, but neither is `StackTrace`.

```
void ValidateProperty(string value)
{
    var setter = (new StackTrace()).GetFrame(1).GetMethod();

    var property = 
        setter.DeclaringType
              .GetProperties()
              .FirstOrDefault(p => p.GetSetMethod() == setter);

    Debug.Assert(property != null);

    var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestMaxStringLengthAttribute), true);

    //Use the attributes to check the length, throw an exception, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could consider, as an alternative approach, delaying validation until later, thus removing the need to inspect the stack trace.

This example provides an attribute...

```
public class MaxStringLengthAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }
    public MaxStringLengthAttribute(int length) { this.MaxLength = length; }
}
```

... a POCO with the attribute applied to a property...

```
public class MyObject
{
    [MaxStringLength(50)]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

... and a utility class stub that validates the object.

```
public class PocoValidator
{
    public static bool ValidateProperties<TValue>(TValue value)
    {
        var type = typeof(TValue);
        var props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            var atts = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MaxStringLengthAttribute), true);
            var propvalue = prop.GetValue(value, null);

            // With the atts in hand, validate the propvalue ...
            // Return false if validation fails.
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooh. I like this approach much better from a coding perspective.  Of course, the attribute decoration is useless unless validation is implemented, which is a little harder to assume in this model, but overall it should be faster and cleaner.

Comment: could you please tell me how to validate the the value against atts? Thanks!